# How to dynamically pass or specify application.yml, when spring boot application is deployed as service in linux?

Tags: spring-boot

I am going through the option of deploying spring boot application as service in linux as specificied in the below docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-initd-service

But here I am not seeing an option how I can specify custom application.yml at the machine. i.e I would like to maintain an application.yml with all the credentials and other details in the machine and pass it to the service, when I call 'service myApp start'.

as mentioned in the documentation, I would be running
$ sudo ln -s /var/myapp/myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp
$ service myapp start

And checking how I can here pass the application.yml path.

Please provide inputs on this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot can read configurations from an external file as well.

Use: `--spring.config.location=<PATH_TO_YAML_FILE>` in the service's "start" script

Example:

```
 java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=file:/application.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options how it could be implemented:

1.Specify path to config file as spring properties

> java -jar myproject.jar
> --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties

2.Use propertyConfigurer bean with environment variable as part of config filename :

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:META-INF/spring/common_configuration.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:META-INF/spring/configuration-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:META-INF/spring/database-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    </bean>
```

3.Profiles
Use standard filename and config location with profile variable as part of name

> application-dev.properties
>
> application-prod.properties
>
> application-test.properties

and setting profile when starting application

> --spring.profiles.active=dev,prod